# Why did C-SPC and C-M-SPC suddenly stopped working while M-h still works?

Tags: key-bindings, osx, mark

I have been comfortably using Emacs in MacOS 13.4.1 (M1 architecture) for a while. However, a few days ago, using the default keybinding of C-SPC for `set-mark-command` simply stopped working. Same for `C-M-SPC` which is associated to `mark-sexp`. Interestingly, other commands such as `M-h` for `mark-paragraph` still work as expected.

This is my [Emacs init file](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/init.el) and as shown in the git log, the file has been stable for a few months. As you see, I have packages that help display which keybinding is associated with each command:

[image]

According to Ivy's buffer, `C-SPC` has not been changed. Thus, I really do not know why this keybinding stopped working.

I can still use the command. But, to do it, I need to invoke `M-x` and then type the command name which reduces my productivity.

Here are the steps I have tried as part of my debugging effort, but unfortunately, they did not work:

1. Re-starting Emacs
2. Re-starting the computer
3. Tried opening default Emacs (without loading my init file with `➜  emacs -q` )
4. Tried using the native Macbook keyboard (instead of my keychron 2)
5. Tried using Emacs without Karabiner Elements running in the background. I am [a heavy user of Karabiner](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-karabiner-elements-config) and it could affect keybindings.
6. I tried invoking `C-h k`. After executing the command, the mini-buffer asks for `Press key:". Even though I press` C-SPC`, Emacs does not acknowledge it. It behaves as if it was waiting for me to press or finish pressing something.

The problem seems to be related to commands that use the `SPC` (space) key.

As a side note, the problem **seems to have** appeared *after* I added "US" as *another* input source on my MacOS keyboard settings. I already had "Brazilian ABNT 2" as one. Not 100% sure on the chronology of the events.

Since it was just an experiment, I added the US input source and, right after, I removed it, restoring the settings to the previous state (only Brazilian input). Not sure if this permanently affected something. This is what I have now:

[image]

Any suggestion on how to debug and/or solve this?

Comment: You always have to debug these things by using `C-h k` to ask Emacs what is bound to the key sequence of interest. Can you add the output to your question?

Comment: Thanks, @db48x. I actually tried that. I just forgot to mention. Now, it is included.

Comment: DO NOT provide an entire `.emacs` file unless it's short enough. Why not cut out the code snippets that are obviously irrelevant?

Comment: Well, to be honest @shynur I posted the emacs file for reproducibility standards. But, the problem does not seem to be related considering that (i) the problem persists even without the config file and (ii) I did not use to have a problem until very recently and the config file has been the same for several months.

Comment: Your desktop environment is intercepting `C-SPC` and it never gets to Emacs.Check the keyboard shortcuts section of the desktop settings (however you do that on MacOS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@[NickD](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/14825/nickd) and @[db48x](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/9982/db48x) helped me realize that the problem was outside of Emacs. The problem was in macOS.

My suspicion is that after tweaking the input source (by removing "Brazilian ABNT" and then re-introducing it), the keyboard shortcut settings were restored to default.

So, it was necessary to go there and turn off the following options:

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Even though I press `C-SPC`, Emacs does not acknowledge it. It behaves as if it was waiting for me to press or finish pressing something.

This is the key. Your OS is treating this key sequence in some special way, either to activate a feature like an IME or as a keyboard shortcut of some kind. Either way, it never sends the key to Emacs. This isn’t an Emacs problem at all; you need to consult the documentation for your OS.